# MongoDB/MySQL - auto increment vs object ID

Tags: mysql, mongodb, php, relational-theory

I am in the process of evaluating MongoDB and writing some basic PHP applications around it. Typically in my PHP/MySQL applications, I would create an ID field and set it to auto-increment on each row insert. I would then use this ID to relate to/join tables together.

However in MongoDB, there is no auto-increment (unless you create function to do it, I believe), only an objectID. Because of this, i'm unsure of how to relate collections together.

Is it worth writing an auto-increment function (as explained here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/), or is it common practice to store the ObjectID?

An example would be the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_type = '2'
```

But in MongoDB....

```
db.cars.find( { car_type : 507c35dd8fada716c89d0013 } );
```

Is the above standard practice? Am I using Mongo incorrectly by creating an auto-increment field?

Darius

EDIT: I think I am so deeply rooted in MySQL that I can't imagine an application without auto-incrementing IDs. Is it safe to store objectIDs (just as you would store a MySQL AI ID)? Is this bad for readability, since you would have to look up that objectID just to see what it relates to?

Comment: MongoDB ObjectIDs also consists a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch, it is kind an auto increment, you can test it by typing `ObjectId("5889ff55736a51703194b3ce").getTimestamp()` returns `ISODate("2017-01-26T13:53:25Z")` , of course it is not exactly an auto increment id but it is ordered already (I don't know what happens if server time changes)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, or almost any other RDBMS, it is common to have an ID for the row (object), so you use it in other tables to make a link between the tables (Relations, or PK and FK if you prefer). This is part of the normalization process that is recommended for most types of DB design [there are exceptions though].

In MongoDB however, the general way or design is to denormalize. i.e. the document (row) is stored with all its related objects.

To make it more clear:

In MySQL you would have two tables: `cars` and `car_types`. In cars you only store the ID of the type of this car.

In Mongo DB, you would have one collection called `car`s, and the document in this collection would have a sub-document that contains the type's info. (You still can have a separate collection for `types`, but you don't store only `objectID` in car's collection)

HTH

Comment: If I create a sub document with the type's info, wouldn't that result in duplicate data (assuming I would be doing this for each 'car' document)?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, `cars` and `car_types` is about the perfect example for linking.

Comment: @Darius, Yes, that will result in duplicate data, and that is what de-normalization is. Design philosophy is different here is 'document store' DBs

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
db.cars.find( { "car_type" : 507c35dd8fada716c89d0013 } );
```

actually would be used and imho is the best solution in this case. In order to make this query efficient, however, you would create an index

```
db.cars.ensureIndex({"car_type":1})
```

In this case, linking two documents makes sense. There are other relations in which embedding documents might be the better choice. For details, please see the [MongoDB docs regarding data modelling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) for details.